# Span cursor style on empty areas. IE8 problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a span with the following style:

```
margin: 5px 0;
padding: 2px;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
width:100%;
background-color:Blue;
```

This works fine with IE6, IE7, FF3 and Chrome, but in IE8 the cursor is changed only in the parts of the span that have text (in other browsers the whole span has the cursor changed).

Any idea of how to fix this problem (I don't want to put the compatibility tag on the page).

Cheers!

**Solution:** The problem was that the spans were inside a floated div, that was causing the problem.

Comment: That code works fine in my IE8 window, the pointer shows up across the whole span. Might be a difference in your IE settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine for me in IE8

Here is a sample:

http://jsbin.com/oqiwo

(add /edit to edit the code)

```
<span style="margin: 5px 0;padding: 2px;cursor: pointer;display: block;width:100%;background-color:Blue;" >Hover over to change cursor to pointer</span>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. It seems that the problem was that the container div had a float:left style, I removed that and the problem vanished.

Answer (score 2):

Add
position: relative
to your current style. The cursor will appear correctly.